Alphabet related reasoning problem.
I think that below type of problems are easy to everyone and not the level of this site but I don't know the rule.
Please see the following 4 situations:
(1) Which letter will be 8th to the right of the 8th letter from the left in the English alphabet?
(2) Which letter will be 8th to the left of the 8th letter from the right in the English alphabet?
(3) Which letter will be 8th to the left of the 8th letter from the left in the English alphabet?
(4) Which letter will be 8th to the right of the 8th letter from the right in the English alphabet?
My Attempt : we know that if we moves Left to right or right to left then we add both place values and count place from left  and left to left or right to right we subtract place values. So in first case,For L to R we have 8+8 = 16, it should be P and for second case,For R to L,  8+8 = 16, 27-16 = 11. it should be K. But in third and fourth case, difference is 0. Then how to obtained correct answer? Please help me.

Try with a smaller number. The 3rd letter from the left is C. Which letter is the 3rd to the left of C? The first to the left of C is B; the second to the left of C is A; then what? There is no 3rd letter to the left of C!

@Karl, from the comment   I understood that no letter found in such situations. Am I right?

I'm no more an expert on alphabets and counting than you are. Trust your common sense.
